# How do you wait one second before completing an action in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm looking to find a way to have HaxeFlixel wait one second before an action, but FlxTimer isn't being useful. Thanks.

Comment: FlxTimer isn't being useful? What do you mean? Are you using it like the example (https://haxeflixel.com/documentation/cheat-sheet/) I don't use HaxeFlixel, so I'd typically use `haxe.Timer.delay(my_callback, 1000);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Create a timer variable and assign a callback function. This code will wait for one second before running the `sayHello()` function:

```
var timer:FlxTimer = new FlxTimer().start(1, sayHello);

...

private function sayHello(timer:FlxTimer)
{
    trace("Hello!!");
}
```